# Use blueimp to upload file from cropperjs

Tags: jquery, file-upload, blueimp, cropperjs

I'm trying to upload an edited image from cropperjs with fileupload.  The fileupload class works on other aspects of the site so I know it works.  When I try to run the add method nothing happens and no errors are in the console.

```
 var canvas =self.cropper.getCroppedCanvas();
 var image = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpg');

 let fileInfo = {
     lastModified: new Date().getTime(),
     name: 'logo.' + fileExtension,
     type: 'image/jpg'
 };

 $('#selector').fileupload();
 $('#selector').fileupload('add', {image, fileInfo});
```

if i do this:
     let r = $('#selector').fileupload();
     alert(JSON.stringify(r));

I get a return from the initialization but it does not fire the add method.  There is a simple alert('dsf'); in the add method and it doesn't popup.  Any ideas on possible problem or how to troubleshoot would be appreciated!  The cropper is running in a dialog box and the blueimp widget is included on the parent page.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps someone else..

```
 $('#selector').fileupload('add', {image, fileInfo});
```

should be

```
 let f = new File([blob], "image.png", {type: "image/png", lastModified: new Date().getTime()});
 $("#selector").fileupload('add',  {files: f} );
```